# Qtorrent web GUI behind Nginx reverse proxy not loading login webpage css

Tags: nginx, bittorrent, nginx-reverse-proxy, torrent, visual-web-gui

Torrent client, qtorrent, has web GUI.

Torrent client on one server with unique ip address.
Nginx reverse proxy setup with unique ip address.

Have setup Nginx reverse proxy to point subdomain address internal ip address with specific port (traffic HTTPS via letsencrypt).

Can load Torrent Client GUI login page, but no page formatting (images provided below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6iZI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbQZu.png)

Can access Torrent Client GUI when on local network, via local ip address:port.

When login details are entered in site (that is accessed via domain address sub.example.com), a blank white web page is loaded and the web address changes to "https://www.sub.example.com/?username=UNameExample&password=PASSWORDExample"

Any advise on where to confirm or check configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below worked for Nginx Reverse Proxy setup for qtorrent.

Original found solution [here](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/8312#issuecomment-364929157).

```
                #
            #Code below is for SSL
            #
            server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
                server_name bittorrent.example.com www.bittorrent.example.com;

                include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            }


            server {
               listen 443 ssl http2;
               server_name bittorrent.example.com;

               ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bittorrent.example.com/fullchain.pem;
               ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bittorrent.example.com/privkey.pem;
               ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bittorrent.example.com/chain.pem;
               include snippets/ssl.conf;
               include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

               return 301 https://www.bittorrent.example.com$request_uri;
            }

            server {
               listen 443 ssl http2;
               server_name www.bittorrent.example.com;

               ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bittorrent.example.com/fullchain.pem;
               ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bittorrent.example.com/privkey.pem;
               ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bittorrent.example.com/chain.pem;
               include snippets/ssl.conf;
               include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

               location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10:9091/;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $server_name:$server_port;
                proxy_hide_header       Referer;
                proxy_hide_header       Origin;
                proxy_set_header        Referer                 '';
                proxy_set_header        Origin                  '';
                add_header              X-Frame-Options         "SAMEORIGIN";
               }
            }
```